# Jenkins : run SSH commands in target host with sh

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I manage my pipeline thanks to a Jenkinsfile. I try to deploy my build app thanks to an ssh connection.

```
stage("Deploy") {
  steps {
    echo "Deploy project..."
    sh """ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa admin@${PROJECT_IP_ADDRESS} 'mkdir /srv/projects/${PROJECT_NAME} -p && chmod 777 /srv/projects/${PROJECT_NAME} '"""
    dir("/srv/projects"){
      //sh """ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa admin@${PROJECT_IP_ADDRESS} 'mkdir /srv/projects/${PROJECT_NAME} && chmod 777 /srv/projects/${PROJECT_NAME}'"""
      sh "scp -r ${PROJECT_NAME} admin@${PROJECT_IP_ADDRESS}:/srv/projects"
    }
  }
}
```

The SSH command is run, but the commands inside are not run :

```
    + ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa admin@<ip>
Warning: Permanently added '<ip>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Linux <ip> #1 SMP Debian <version> (2021-03-19) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

The connection is successful, but the ssh connection is never stopped. When I run the command in a terminal with the Jenkins user, it's a success.

Anyone have an idea to fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Has exactly the same issue, tried different answers from the Related questions but none of then are working for me at the moment

Comment: In my case, I fix the problem when I change my deploiement method. I'm using Terraform to deploy my app now. So the SSH commands issues are fixed.